# Extract Field Values from Link Issues

Tags: groovy, jira

I want to check if the field values in the "Issues" field is null or not using a groovy script as a validator. As there are certain scenarios that will require the user to fill in this field, however not always so I cannot make it just a required field.

[image: Picture of Fields]

So it would be the latter field "Issue" is what I want to see if it is null. And to be able to check the status of "Link Issue".

EDIT: This gave me the appropriate solution for the issue at hand. https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/14203790/how-to-set-linked-issues-as-mandatory-field-on-issue-creation

Comment: Your screenshot is from the dialog to add a link to another issue. Custom Validators (groovy scripts or other ones added by plugins) are run as part of transitions in your workflow. Adding a link does not transition the issue, so you cannot use a validator here. Can you give a bit more detail about what you're trying to do? Maybe there is a way.

Comment: @GlennV Sorry if I wasn't specific enough. I just want to check if the link issue and issues fields are null. So if the user sets the Solution to Fixed By or Duplicate I want the validator to check after he/she submits the form, that the Issue field is not null. And that the Link Issue field is set to the correct one from the drop down list.